# Force Apache to return Content-Length for regular PHP pages?

Tags: ajax, loader, content-length

I am bulding an ajax website and it needs to have a percentage loader for the new pages. New pages are ajax loaded, cached and slided with animation. Anyway, in order to do that, I need to fetch somehow the size of the content I am going to receive during the current request, in order to calculate the percentage. Unfortunately it does not set the `Content-Length` header for pages, but just for files. Can I force it to always add the header? Any other way to create this percentage loader? Any ideas will be helpful. Thanks!